# GitBash "No such file or directory" con Proyecto R existente / with existing R Project

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Intentando adherir un proyecto ya existente a version control con GitBash para un curso online. He intentado agregar "" a las carpetas con espacios (Data Science - JHU), sin embargo obtengo "cd: too many arguments". Agradecería una mano de alguien con un poco de experiencia.

[image: Imagen/Image. En la imagen las lineas no empiezan con cd ~/Desktop/etc. sin embargo si lo he usado, pueden ignorar ese hecho, he editado la imagen incorrecta.]

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado: el problema era otro no relacionado a estos programas o version control. Los comandos y los programas no tienen ningun problema.